# Copy a file and paste to multiple folders

Tags: batch-file

I want to copy a file and paste that file to multiple folders.

Designation path : `c:\exam\*\mark`, `*` is subject. I have many folders with different subjects.
I am using a batch file like,

```
for /d %%a in ("c:\exam\*\mark") do copy "C:\name\add.txt" "%%a"
```

but this is not working for me, please give a suggestion to correct this code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

one loop is enough:

```
for /d %%a in (c:\exam\*) do if exist "%%~a\mark\" copy "C:\name\add.txt" "%%~a\mark"
```

Comment: This is working fine. If i need to jump two or more folders what can i do? like, "c:\exam\\*\\*\\*\mark"

Answer (score 3):

`for /d` can't handle wildcharacters inside a path, it's only allowed in the last element.

But you can simply try to copy to the destination, if the destination path doesn't exist it fails and the error will redirected to nul.
Or you can test first if the destination exists, like Endoro showed.

```
for /d %%a in ("c:\exam\*") do (
    copy "C:\name\add.txt" "%%a\mark\" 2> nul
)
```

Comment: Its not working for me. Batch file is running success but coping is not working.

Comment: How does it fail? What do you get when you insert `ECHO %%a %%b` ?

Comment: This is looking for `C:\exam\*\mark\*\ ` instead of `C:\exam\*\mark\ `!

Comment: @LS_dev Aaarg, you are right, I tested a wrong scenario. I changed my answer to a working one